# useEffect exceso de calls REACT

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un **json-server** que contiene **objetos** `{ "id" : x , "name" : y }` el ejercicio es simple, llamar con una función asíncrona y cargar los datos, para ello también he realizado un formulario en un componente, en el cual escribes solo el nombre y se añade de forma asíncrona al **json-server**.

El problema es cuando una vez que he añadido el nuevo **item** al **json-sever** este no se visualiza en cliente hasta que realizo un refresh de la pagina... Mi idea era usar un `useEffect` para provocar un renderizado en el componente que almacena la carga del servidor **json-server** de los datos.

Pero al pasar le dicho componente, este realiza llamadas infinitas al servidor reduciendo su eficiencia y haciendo llamadas innecesarias. Como podría solucionarlo ?

**Main.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MainItem from './MainItem';
import Form from './Form';

function Main(){

    const[customer,setCustomer] = useState([]);

    async function loadData(){
        const url = 'http://localhost:3004/personal';
        const end = await fetch(url);
        const json = await end.json();
        return json;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData().then(customer => {
            setCustomer(customer);
        })
    },[])

    //Si pasas por el useEffect customer, hace infinitas peticiones al servidor!!!

    return(
        <main>
            <div className="main-container">
                {customer.map(c => <MainItem id={c.id} name={c.name} key={c.id} />)}
            </div>
            <div className="main-container">
                <Form />
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

**MainItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function MainItem({id,name}){
    return(
        <div className="item">{name}</div>
    );
}

export default MainItem;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Form(){

    const[name,setName] = useState("");

    const handleName = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    }

    async function addName(){
       const newItem = {id : Date.now(), name : name};
       const url = 'http://localhost:3004/personal'; //URL 

       const end = await fetch(url, {method: 'POST', //End point a la URL 
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(newItem),
       });

       const json = await end.json(); // JSON format
       return json;
    }

    function loadName(){
        addName();
        setName("");
    }

    return(
        <form>
            <input 
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={e => handleName(e)}
            placeholder="Name"
            />
            <input type="button" onClick={loadName} value="Add"  />
        </form>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "personal": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Maria"
    }
  ]
}
```

Si introduces el nombre en el formulario se actualiza en el **server** pero no se muestra en cliente hasta que no se refresca la pagina como podría hacerlo usando `useEffect` ?

He probado a introducir esto pero genera infinitas llamadas al server :

```
useEffect(() => {
     loadData().then(customer => {
         etCustomer(customer);
     })
},[customer])
```

Answer (score 2):

#### useEffect dependency: comparación por valor vs comparación por referencia

El hook `useEffect` se esta disparando `n` veces, porque la referencia de `customer` que se pasa como `dependency`, cambia cada vez que `ReactJs` devuelve el componente nuevamente, nótese que `customer` es un tipo `Array`:

```
//ReactJs: const customer es una nueva referencia en cada devolucion
const[customer,setCustomer] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
     loadData().then(customer => {
         etCustomer(customer);
     })
//ReactJs: la referencia customer es diferente, ha cambiado, por lo tanto disparo el efecto
},[customer])
```

En las dependencias del hook `useEffect`, se deben listar siempre que sea posible, tipos primitivos (String,Int,Boolean ...etc), de tal forma que `useEffect` compare igualdad por valor, en vez de comparar igualdad por referencia, como pasa en este caso con el tipo `Array` (o el resto de los tipos de datos `Object` y `function`).

---

#### Propuesta

Se puede declarar un nuevo estado con tipo primitivo `Boolean` que se usará como depenencia de `useEffect`, su función será actuar como `bandera`, para saber cuando el usuario a realizado una operación de escritura en el servidor:

```
 //componente home
 const [reloadData, setReloadData] = useState(false);
        
 useEffect(() => {
     loadData().then(customer => {
         setCustomer(customer);
     })
     //ReactJs: al desmontar el componente regresare la bandera reloadData a su valor inicial
     return ()=>setReloadData(false);
    //ReactJs: dependencia primitiva, voy a comparar igualdad por valor
 },[reloadData])
```

Luego, se pasa el setter `setReloadData` como `props` al componente `Form`:

```
<Form reloadHandler={setReloadData}/>
```

Destructurando `props`en componente `Form`:

```
function Form({reloadHandler}){
//...code
}
```

Después, en el componente `Form`, se llama a `reloadHandler` y además, se cambia el valor del estado `setReload` que es un tipo primitivo `Boolean`, de `false` a `true`:

```
function loadName(){
      addName();
      setName("");
      reloadHandler(true);
  }
```

Con esto, `useEffect` se dispará al momento de devolver nuevamente la `App`, pues el valor de la dependencia `reloadData` ha cambiado.

Finalmente, se cargan los datos más recientes de `customer`, solo si el usuario realizó la operación de escritura al server.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias por la explicación, lo tendré en cuenta para las próximas veces.